# how to find the effective way in a d-heap array with approach design of DelMin algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I need to write an d-heap array to find the minimum with an effective way, I have coded an algorithm already which finds it but i believe someone help me to find an easiest way to find it, could someone please help me with an alternative way of finding it please?

My code:

```
Heap delMin(d, heap){
    heap.array[0] := heap.array[idx];
    heap.idx := heap.idx-1;
    downHeap(heap.array, heap.idx, 0, d);
    return heap;
}

//-------------------------------------------
downHeap(array[], n, k, d) {
    int currentElement;
    int firstSuccessorIndex;
    currentElement := array[k];
    smallestChildIndex = findSmallestChildIndex(array, n, currentElement, d);
    if( smallestChildIndex == -1 || currentElement < array[smallestChildIndex] )
    {
        return;
    } else {
        swap(array, k, smallestChildIndex);
        downHeap(array, n, smallestChildIndex, d);
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------
int findSmallestChildIndex(array[], n, k, d) {
    firstChildIndex = array[k*d + 1];
    if(firstChildIndex > n){
        return -1; //the element is a leaf
    }
    lastChildIndex = array[k*d + d];
    if(lastChildIndex > n) {
        lastChildIndex = n;
    }
    smallestChildIndex = firstChildIndex;
    for(int i=firstChildIndex; i < lastChildIndex; i++)
    {
        if(array[i] < array[smallestChildIndex]) {
            smallestChildIndex = array[i];
        }
    }
    return smallestChildIndex;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have edited your question and supplied indentation. In the future, please ensure that your code is nicely formatted. The editor doesn't like tabs, so you need to replace them with spaces.

Comment: The algorithm you selected for `DelMin` is the standard way of doing things. Does your code work? If it does not work, please describe the error that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have errors in your `findSmallestChildIndex` function, when you are computing indexes. For example, you have:

```
firstChildIndex = array[k*d + 1];
```

That doesn't get the index of the first child. Rather, it gets the value at the first child index. The *index* is equal to `k*d + 1`.

That error occurs in multiple places in the function.

Also, I think you want to ensure that `firstChildIndex` is always less than `n`, not less than or equal to `n`. I've made that change, too.

The corrected code is:

```
int findSmallestChildIndex(array[], n, k, d) {
    firstChildIndex = k*d + 1;
    if(firstChildIndex >= n){
        return -1; //the element is a leaf
    }
    lastChildIndex = k*d + d;
    if(lastChildIndex > n) {
        lastChildIndex = n;
    }
    smallestChildIndex = firstChildIndex;
    for(int i=firstChildIndex; i < lastChildIndex; i++)
    {
        if(array[i] < array[smallestChildIndex]) {
            smallestChildIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return smallestChildIndex;
}
```